# Pull a distinct, single value from MySQL Database via PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have this SQL statement which pulls ONE value (the `OrderID`) from the orders table.

```
"SELECT DISTINCT (MAX(OrderID)) FROM orders WHERE Username = 'hello@hello.com';
```

I run that via PHPMyAdmin and it returns one Order ID for that user which is EXACTLY what I want. However, I am trying to run this in PHP...

```
"SELECT DISTINCT (MAX(OrderID)) FROM orders WHERE Username = '". $_SESSION['Username'] ."'";
```

I want that to pull the Order ID so I can then set `$OrderID = (the result from the select statement)`, then run an update statement as below.

```
$sql = "UPDATE orders SET Status = 'Failed' WHERE Status = 'Success' and OrderID = ". $OrderID ."";
```

If I hard code `$OrderID = 90;` it works perfectly but I need the OrderID to pull through via the session of who is logged in.

Complete code:

```
<?php
$url = 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

if (strpos($url,'order-failed') !== false) {
    $servername = "NULL";
    $username = "NULL";
    $password = "NULL";
    $dbname = "NULL";

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    // Check Connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }

    $query = "SELECT DISTINCT (MAX(OrderID)) FROM orders WHERE Username = '". $_SESSION['Username'] ."'";
    echo $query . "<br />";

    $OrderID = 93;
    echo $OrderID;
    echo "<br />";
    $sql = "UPDATE orders SET Status = 'Failed' WHERE Status = 'Success' and OrderID = ". $OrderID ."";
    echo $sql;

    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "<br />Record updated successfully";
    }

    else {
        echo "<br />Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
    }

    $conn->close();
}

else {
    session_destroy();
}
?>
```

Comment: so then dont you think the proplem in storing $_SESSION['Username']? show as the code about it

Comment: Are you sure you get something from your session $_SESSION['Username'] ?

Comment: Have you verified that your session variables are being created and are active within the current page?

Comment: The Session is fine and I can echo that out perfectly. :) If I echo out the Select statement I get...

SELECT DISTINCT (MAX(OrderID)) FROM orders WHERE Username = 'email@test.com'

This is exactly what I need. Why is it echoing out the query rather than the result?

Comment: Added to original question.

Comment: I can't see `session_start()` at the top of your file. Are you sure it isn't the issue?

Comment: You have to send the first query (the "SELECT DISTINCT....") to the mysql server and then fetch the result record(s); not just stuffing the query in a (php) string....

Comment: How do I go about that VolkerK?

Comment: Almost the same way as you did with the second query. `$result = $conn->query($query)`. Then check whether $result is not falsy (that would indicate an error) and fetch the record, see http://docs.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.examples-basic.php

Comment: @VolkerK there is only ONE result, if I run it via PHPMyAdmin I get a number, for example. 1, 2, 3, 4 or 5 - it can be anything... OrderID is an auto incrementing column. How would I pull that ONE value? Can you send me the code?

Comment: It's a record anyway, you have to send the query and fetch the record if the query was successful.

Comment: DISTINCT is not a function, and is entirely redundant in this context (as is your first query in its entirety!!)

Comment: I have removed DISTINCT.

Answer (score 3):

It seems like this would have the same effect...

```
$sql = "
UPDATE orders 
   SET Status = 'Failed' 
 WHERE Status = 'Success'
   AND Username = '{$_SESSION['Username']}'
 ORDER 
    BY OrderID DESC 
 LIMIT 1;
    ";
```

... although obviously rewrite it to use prepared statement syntax

Comment: I think without the `(WHERE) Status = 'Success'` condition it would be identical. The original code might select an order_id for a record already having status==failed, so the update would be without consequence (if orderid really is unique) while your query could in this case update another record.

Comment: @VolkerK You've lost me there I'm afraid.

Comment: Consider the table contains only the two records `[oid=17,usrname=usrA,status=f],[oid=16,usrname=usrA,status=s]`. The original script picks orderid=17 and the update does nothing/the table keeps unchanged. Your query results in `[oid=16,usrname=usrA,status=f]` because it just skips the oid=17 record because status=f doesn't match the WHERE clause.

Comment: OK - fair point, so you could use an uncorrelated subquery (for instance) instead

Comment: no no, just remove the `Status = 'Success` condition. The query then will always work on the "first" record (with the highest orderid). If this record already contains `failed`, nothing changes but the LIMIT clause still is "triggered" -> same behaviour as the original query (unless there are more possible states for `status`, but this could be handled, too). That only one query is required is a good catch anyway :-)

Comment: Ah yes - assuming status only has those two values

Answer (score 0):

add session start on top

```
<?php
session_start();
// your code here
```

Comment: I have that. It's nothing to do with the Sessions, they are all working correctly. :)

Comment: @DanAshbridge can you `var_dump($_SESSION);` to see what was in the belly

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
echo $query . "<br />";

$OrderID = 93;
echo $OrderID;
echo "<br />";
```

with

```
$result = $conn->query($query);
$row = $result->fetch_row();
$OrderID = $row[0];
```

and do what all other guys said

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-row.php

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php

Comment: not sure author bothered about it right now. later - sure

Answer (score -1):

Firstly it might be wise to test that the session variable exists and in the select statement assign an alias to the max() function.

```
if( isset( $_SESSION['Username'] ) ){
    /* Only gets called if the session var exists */
    $sql="SELECT DISTINCT MAX(`OrderID`) as 'OrderID' FROM `orders` WHERE `Username` = '". $_SESSION['Username'] ."';";

    /* run this query, get the OrderID record from results and prepare the next sql statement */

    $sql = "UPDATE `orders` SET `Status` = 'Failed' WHERE `Status` = 'Success' and `OrderID` = ". $OrderID ."";


    /* Alternatively perhaps do it in one statement */
    $sql="UPDATE `orders` SET `Status` = 'Failed' 
          WHERE `Status` = 'Success' and `OrderID` = (
              SELECT DISTINCT MAX(`OrderID`) FROM `orders` WHERE `Username` = '". $_SESSION['Username'] ."'
          )";
}
```

Comment: I don't know how to "run this query, get the OrderID record from results"... This is my only problem, the rest I can do! There will only ever be one value returned from the Select Statement.